# How can I connect to my REST API with powershell (CYPHERTRUST)

Tags: powershell, api, rest, post

I am searching for how to connect to my rest API with a Powershell script

I know that I need to send my Body with the POST Method but can't define how to do it

There is documentation where they talk about tokens:

Its what I need to call with Invoke Rest-Method

```
https://10.75.8.128/playground_v2/api/Tokens#/v1/auth/tokens/-post
```

And there is that body that I need to send :

```
{
  "grant_type": "password",
  "username": "steve",
  "password": "mysecretword",
  "labels": [
    "myapp",
    "cli"
  ]
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
$person = @{
  "grant_type": "password",
  "username": "username",
  "password": "MDP",
  "labels": [
    "myapp",
    "cli"
  ]
}
```

Invoke-RestMethod

```
$person "https://10.75.8.128/playground_v2/api/v1/auth/tokens" -Method Post
```

Comment: Have you tried modifying Example 2 to match your needs?  Looks like you could copy the code, remove the parts related to $Cred, modify the content of $Body, etc... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod#example-2-run-a-post-request

Comment: Yes i tried with this method but when I want to execute it, it just make a line break

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me just fine:

```
$username = "admin"
$password = "password"
$Url = "https://$ciphertrust-manager-ip/api/v1/auth/tokens"
$Body = @{
    grant_type = "password"
    username = $username
    password = $password
    labels = @('myApp', 'cli')
}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $Url -Body $body
$jwt = $response.jwt
```

Got the jwt token back from the JSON response received from Ciphertrust Manager.

Hope this helps.

side note: I am not sure if it is required... I did create a sample powershell script to perform a few complex API operations on ciphertrust manager that would otherwise require quite a few UI based steps. [GitHub Link Here](https://github.com/anugram/BankingApp-CM29_DPG11/blob/main/deploy-demo-win-ps.ps1)